# The re-phrased new questions/ close as identical?

Tags: discussion

Recently there's been a series of questions that started out simply enough, i.e. the first of the series was not an issue. 
Soon after, the same poster put up slight variations, posted as new questions, which after a time became tedious. Many of them were downvoted, some closed.

Any thoughts on this type of situation? My 'vote to close' cited his similar question, and he took offense, spelling out the slight difference the new question had.

Is 'close enough' the same as 'exact duplicate' or are any variations on a question welcome until exhausted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be closed. There was another user sometime back, who wanted to make it rich by taking a 1 Million unsecured loan from Bank and investing in Facebook IPO and getting rich when it listed. He asked more than a dozen questions just to get his wish true somehow.

Answer (score 6):

Minor variations of a bad question are likely bad questions also